# What devices is the iPod to Firewire 400 adapter meant for, and for what purpose?

Tags: ipod, firewire

I have this adapter:

[image]

Is it completely useless? I'm not quite sure what it is. I've had it for years.

Comment: Not at all, please put it in an envelope to me and I'll dispose of it for you safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Firewire 400 to iPod 30-pin adapter.

If you have an older iPod, you may be able to sync and/or charge it via Firewire. This site has an exhaustive list: [Which iPods can sync and charge via USB? Which iPods can sync and charge via Firewire?](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipod/ipod-faq/ipods-charge-and-sync-firewire-usb2.html)

It looks like some models supported Firewire charging as recently as 2009, but no models since 2006 or so have the ability to sync media over Firewire.

Answer (score 1):

Many Apple portable devices used to support charging and syncing over FireWire. It was actually quite nice, because FireWire charged iPods significantly quicker than USB can. I believe these are the devices that support FireWire charging and/or syncing:

- iPhone (1st gen only)
- iPod (5th gen or earlier)
- iPod nano (2nd gen or earlier)
- iPod mini